# What is the correct oembed provider base url for self-hosted wordpress sites

Tags: oembed

I used to have both PCsteps.gr and Lifesteps.gr on the same server with the same IP. Oembed would work by default, I could embed posts from one site to the other without any problems.

However, since moving lifesteps.gr on a different server, embeds won't work anymore. It is my understanding that to embed lifesteps posts to pcsteps, I need to add lifesteps as an oembed provider to pcsteps.

I have added the following code, that I have created [here](https://generatewp.com/oembed/).

```
    // Register oEmbed providers
function custom_oembed_provider() {

    wp_oembed_add_provider( 'https://www.lifesteps.gr/*', 'https://www.lifesteps.gr/oembed/', false );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_oembed_provider' );
```

However, this doesn't work. I suspect that the https://www.lifesteps.gr/oembed/ base url that I am using is wrong. However, I couldn't find if there is a default type for base oembed url for self-hosted wordpress sites.

Answer (score 0):

In order for [oEmbeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) to work when embedding another WordPress site, the single template must have discovery links enabled. WordPress uses these to retrieve the oEmbed endpoint where the content is retrieved. These endpoints are a part of the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/), so make sure that's enabled and working as well.

> [`wp-includes/embed.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/embed.php#L322) v5.1.1

```
if ( is_singular() ) {
    $output .= '<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="' . esc_url( get_oembed_endpoint_url( get_permalink() ) ) . '" />' . "\n";

    if ( class_exists( 'SimpleXMLElement' ) ) {
        $output .= '<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="' . esc_url( get_oembed_endpoint_url( get_permalink(), 'xml' ) ) . '" />' . "\n";
    }
}
```

Here's an example of that output:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="https://yourdomain.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fyourdomain.com%2F2019%2F04%2F12%2Fpost%2F">
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="https://yourdomain.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fyourdomain.com%2F2019%2F04%2F12%2Fpost%2F&amp;format=xml">
```